# Regular expression to delete all words between two specific words

Tags: regex

I'm normally ok with regex but I'm struggling with this.

I have a simple file with two words that start and end a set of data. The data between the words changes but - start and status are always in the same place.

Example :

**start
Everything in between
status**

I'm trying to work out how to delete (replace) everything between and including start and status

I'm sure I had it working with this at one time

(?i)^start.+?status

set(#replaceAll,$replace regular expression(#textTest,"(?i)^start.+?status"," "),"Global")

but its just not working anymore.

Comment: What are you looking for it to return? `startstatus`? if so, just set your replacement text to "startstatus" and it'll work.

Comment: I'm not looking to return anything - I'm trying to work out how to delete (replace) everything between and including start and status

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regular expression

```
\bstart\b.+?\bstatus\b
```

which does not require `"status"` to be on the same line as `"start"`. Two flags should be set:

- case indifference (`/i`)
- single-line mode, which allows `.` to match a newline (`/s`)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WzBGM4/2/)

The regex reads, "match 'start' with a word break fore and aft (to avoid matching 'starting' or 'jumpstart', for example), then match one or more characters lazily, then match 'status' with wordbreaks". The middle match must be lazy so that the regex engine will stop at the next (rather than last) instance of 'status'.

If the regex engine being used does not support single-line mode, or something comparable, one can replace `.+` with `[\s\S]+`.

Answer (score 0):

So my original expression works and so dose Cary's

The files have changed since I last used the expression. They contain some white-space in the form of newlines that needed to be removed first

```
set(#cleanup,$replace(#text2,$new line," "),"Global")
set(#text2,$replace regular expression(#cleanup,"\\bstart\\b.*?\\bstatus\\b",""),"Global")
set(#cleanup,$replace regular expression(#cleanup,"(?i)^start.+?status:",""),"Global")
```

Sorry about that but thanks to all who looked and helped :)